# JavaFX runs in VSCode but JavaFX with Scene Builder gives "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx, scenebuilder

**Summary of issue/goal:**

I wish to make a JavaFX GUI with Scene Builder in VSCode. A simple 'hello world' program runs in VSCode without issue. I can additionally run a simple 'hello world' JavaFX code in VSCode without issue. However, the JavaFX with Scene Builder code gives me an error.

This may be part of the issue, but 'Run Code' only works for non-JavaFX 'hello world'. The only way to run JavaFX (non-Scene Builder) is via 'Run Java'.

**Versions:**

- VSCode is up to date (v1.76)
- JavaFX was downloaded in past week or so (v19.0.2.1)
- Scene Builder was installed in past week or so (19.0.0 probably)

**Related Extensions (no links; post marked spam and trying to get around it):**

- Extension Pack for Java
- JavaFX Support
- Maven for Java (not sure if related)
- Project Manager for Java (not sure if related)
- SceneBuilder extension for Visual Studio Code

**In detail (sorry, this will be a lot of code; wanted to give as much information possible):**

*Simple Hello World:*

```
public class testing
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("HI");
    }    
}
```

This code runs in 'Run Code' and 'Run Java' with output being `HI`.

*JavaFX Hello World:*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    
    /** 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Using 'Run Code' gives 20 errors, here are two (my question was marked spam, maybe this changes it...?):

```
HelloWorld.java:1: error: package javafx.application does not exist
import javafx.application.Application;
                         ^
HelloWorld.java:2: error: package javafx.event does not exist
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
20 errors
```

Using 'Run Java' gives the expected output: a window with a button saying "Say 'Hello World'" that prints "Hello World!" to the console upon click. Image: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NisSK.png)

*More complicated Scene Builder*

Code comes from [this Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/AubJaosfI-0).

Here is the .fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="417.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainSceneController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="392.0" text="Title" />
      <TextField fx:id="tfTitle" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="392.0" />
      <Button layoutX="184.0" layoutY="359.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnOkClicked" text="OK" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "testing",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "testing",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "TestingBasic",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "TestingBasic",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "App",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "HelloWorld",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path C:/openjfx-19.0.2.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "HelloWorld",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is MainSceneController.fxml:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainSceneController {

    @FXML
    private TextField tfTitle;

    @FXML
    void btnOkClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage mainWindow = (Stage) tfTitle.getScene().getWindow();
        String title = tfTitle.getText();
        mainWindow.setTitle(title);

    }

}
```

Here is the App.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
        
  Parent root;
try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
}
  
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("got here");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

No code has errors. Running `main` in `App.java` produces

`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`.

('Run Java' for App.java gives same thing; 'Run Code' for App.java gives 14 errors similar to the 20 earlier about java.fx packages not existing.)

I am confused what this means.

For reference, here is the 'Configure runtime for projects' page:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL60U.png). I have two options (17 and 19), but both fail and give me the runtime error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qk2R.png).

---

If you could point me in the correct direction, that'd be great. I am new to StackOverflow so I appreciate the support and apologize if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Typically, that error means the main class is a subclass of `javafx.application.Application` _and_ JavaFX was placed on the class-path instead of the module-path (more specifically, that the `javafx.graphics` module is not in the boot `ModuleLayer`). And the fix is to put JavaFX on the `--module-path` and, if your own code is not modular, use `--add-modules` as needed. I see that in one of your configurations, but not all of them; perhaps that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @Slaw: thanks for replying. I'm not quite sure what you mean. How would I put JavaFX on the ```--module-path``` or how would I ```--add-modules```? Is this in the launch.json? I realized additionally that when I place all my files inside a 'src folder' then it makes the non Scene Builder but JavaFX hello world give the same error about runtime. I tried re-doing my vmArgs path a lot from other solutions but that didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I see now. I think I have it working, and I'm not getting the error now. After I figure out something (probably unrelated) I'll explain in an answer for other people with this problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are instructions for VSCode+JavaFX setup at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  I recommend those official instructions over videos on the internet.  Quickly reviewing your setup, it seems that you have most things right, but I don't use VSCode, so cannot verify.  Perhaps follow the instructions at openjfx.io exactly for a new hello world JavaFX project and check that you can get that to work in your environment.

Comment: @Oliver A   Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Slaw for pointing me in the right direction.

**Solution:**
It is a silly mistake. From my starting configuration I just had to:

- Place all my files in a folder called src.
- The vmArgs part needs to be placed for *all* the files using JavaFX

For src folder: not sure why I need it, but taking them out caused problems.

For vmArgs: the section of form `"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",` in `launch.json` must be used for each 'type' that uses JavaFX.

For example, here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "testing",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "src.testing",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "testing",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "testing",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "TestingBasic",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "TestingBasic",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "App",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "App",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "HelloWorld",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Users/Oliver/Downloads/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "HelloWorld",
            "projectName": "Java VSCode test_a97e49e3"
        }
    ]
}
```

to run all the java files in there. For people of my skill level note that: the vmArgs portion is in each and every* section; each section applies to each file (or java class) you are running.

*Technically not

Answer (score 0):

I guess something wrong happens when you launch your JavaFX application.

1. For the first question
   `Run Code` and `Run Java` are contributed from different extensions actually. The former one is contributed by Code Runner while the latter one from Java Debugger extension. I recommend to always use `Run Java` because the Code runner cannot understand your project's dependencies, you will get errors when your file uses third party libraries.
2. For the second question
   Can you try to launch your project directly from the launch panel and make sure the last configuration `HelloWorld` is selected?
   [image]